# Can't select photo and video at the same time from New Google Photos App

Tags: android, google-photos

After Google Photos update I can't select video and photo at the same time. If I use single "video/*" or "image/*" intent it works as usually. In the video-photo intent it ignores second parameter. If the first is video - it will be video intent, if it is photo - you will suggested to choose photo.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("video/*,image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getFileUri());
    startActivityForResult(intent, 911);
```

Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: same here, @rocknow, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Jacky no, i haven't

Answer (score -1):

For some reason Google Photos stopped responding to the second type if you set them on an ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent. It will also ignore the second type if you don't set the Uri. This code should work though:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("video/*,image/*");
```