# Getting both Photos and Videos from the new Google Photos app on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, google-photos

I'd like the user to import a bunch of videos/photos into my app. This is the code I was using before:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setType("image/*,video/*");
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_MEDIA);
```

The problem I'm having is that the above returns only Photos from the new Google Photos app. If I change the data type to 'video/*' only, the Photos app returns videos. This is for KitKat+

EDIT:

I've tried the following code - it works on some galleries but not with most and not Google Photos:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    if (AndroidHelper.isKitKatAndAbove()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Pick from gallery (KitKat+)");
        String[] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "video/*"};
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_MEDIA);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Pick from gallery (Compatibility)");
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_MEDIA);
    }
```

Comment: I'm stuck on the same stupid bug (thank you Google). Have you find a solution?

Comment: Yeah I think so, will post it as an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617255/cant-select-photo-and-video-at-the-same-time-from-new-google-photos-app

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        if (AndroidHelper.isKitKatAndAbove()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Pick from gallery (KitKat+)");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_MEDIA);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Pick from gallery (Compatibility)");
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_MEDIA);
        }
```

Then when I get results, I check the type of the file. Seems to be working fine.

Comment: Yes, but it's kind of an hack, because we only wanted images and videos showing up, this approach allows every type of file. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I agree that's a bit of a hack and therefore I didn't post it before :) If you come up with a better solution, please feel free to post an answer - I'm not going to select my own answer as the answer for this one.

Comment: Well, it is the only solution as of now :) Thanks !

Comment: Shame on Google.

Comment: Wrote about this here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123811931 . Please consider starring it. For now, I've alos written a bit nicer way to choose files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54502555/878126